# How to execute this as admin in windows 8.1?

Tags: node.js, windows, google-chrome

I have to submit this as admin in windows 8.1 how?

`bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures`

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var win = gui.Window.get();

var child;
var run_void;
var input = gui.App.argv;

function runme(input){
  child = exec(input, function (error, stdout, stderr) { 
    sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout); 
    sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr); 
    if (error !== null) { 
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
  }); 

  child.on('exit', function(code) {
      gui.App.quit();
      console.log('Child process exited '+ code);
    });  
}

window.onload = function() {
    // this works
    runme('java -cp kiosk.jar kiosk');  
    // ???
    runme('how to execute the bcdedit as admin?');
};
```

Comment: I am only able to run administrator-privileged commands by running the nodejs script itself in a cmd/ps with admin rights... Looking for an answer too...